# Find gradient of this implicit function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How to find a gradient of this implicit function?
$$
xz+yz^2-3xy-3=0
$$

Comment: Use implicit differentiation to solve for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Comment: $$
\frac{∂z}{∂x} = z-3y
$$
am I right?

Comment: $z + x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} - 3y = 0$.  Do you see why?

Comment: @Sammy Black, no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Abhinav pointed out a mistake, which has been corrected for posterity.

To find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ by implicit differentiation means to differentiate both sides of the equation *with respect to $x$,* while remembering that $z$ is *implicitly* a function of $x$ (we didn't write it with function notation such as $z(x)$).  Don't forget to use the product rule when differentiating a product!
$$
\begin{align}
xz + yz^2 - 3xy - 3 &= 0 \\
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ xz + yz^2 - 3xy - 3 \right] &= \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ 0 \right] \\
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ xz \right] + \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ yz^2 \right] - \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ 3xy \right] - \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ 3 \right] &= 0 \\
\left[ 1 \cdot z + x \cdot \tfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right] + y \cdot 2z \tfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} - 3y - 0 &= 0 \\
z + x \tfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} + 2yz \tfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} - 3y &= 0
\end{align}
$$
This yields
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{3y - z}{x + 2yz}.
$$

Try to find $\tfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ in an analogous way, and post your result in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand nearly everything. 
Trying to $$ \frac{∂z}{∂y} $$ I ended up with:
$$
(z^2+y*\frac{∂z^2}{∂y})-3x=0
$$
what should I do with:
$$
\frac{∂z^2}{∂y}
$$
to get:
$$
\frac{∂z}{∂y}
$$

Comment: $\frac{\partial z^2}{\partial y} = 2z \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$, by the chain rule.

Comment: ok, thank you very much :), now I understand :))

Comment: If you want, you can write $w = z^2$, then the calculation is $\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Comment: If z is considered as z(x), why was the term y(z(x)^2) reduced to zero, rather than 2yz(x). [del(z)/del(x)] ?

Comment: You are correct, @Abhinav. That was a mistake. I edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

By using implicit differentation, determine the gradient of curve $3xy+y^2= -2$ at the point $(1,-3)$

Comment: This does not exactly add value as an answer.

Comment: Perhaps it would benefit Readers if you show how to carry out the proposed calculation and arrive at an answer.  It is an older Question (two years at this point) so terseness at the expense of clarity is not much of a virtue.